# How to sound audible bell from crontab

Tags: audio, cron

The command line:

```
/bin/echo -e "\007"
```

in bash will ring the bell. With the line:

```
* * * * *   /bin/echo -e "\007"
```

in my crontab I expected the bell to ring every minute, but it's silent.
I know crontab is working because the line:

```
* * * * *   /bin/touch $HOME/jkjkjk
```

updates the file `jkjkjk` every minute as it should. I found a posting some years ago suggesting that standard output should be directed to `/dev/tty1` in crontab. But the line:

```
* * * * *   /bin/echo "\007" >/dev/tty1
```

still fails. What to try next?

Answer (score 0):

there is a program called "[beep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep)" which might help.

> beep - beep the pc speaker any number of ways